# what are these interfaces

Tags: android, interface, sdk

I wrote a code to gather the network usage statistics. When I ran it I got the below results. what are the interfaces pdp0 and tun10 in these statistics. Are they 3g interfaces? I am running this app on samsung galaxy phone

> {\"data\":{\"pdp0:\":{\"recv\":{\"packets\":\"8580\",\"bytes\":\"9227448\"},\"sent\":{\"packets\":\"5725\",\"bytes\":\"479019\"}},\"gre0:\":{\"recv\":{\"packets\":\"0\",\"bytes\":\"0\"},\"sent\":{\"packets\":\"0\",\"bytes\":\"0\"}},\"tunl0:\":{\"recv\":{\"packets\":\"0\",\"bytes\":\"0\"},\"sent\":{\"packets\":\"0\",\"bytes\":\"0\"}},\"usb0:\":{\"recv\":{\"packets\":\"0\",\"bytes\":\"0\"},\"sent\":{\"packets\":\"0\",\"bytes\":\"0\"}},\"lo:\":{\"recv\":{\"packets\":\"14908\",\"bytes\":\"713035\"},\"sent\":{\"packets\":\"14908\",\"bytes\":\"713035\"}}},\"ver\":\"1.4\",\"type\":\"netdev\",\"date\":\"2011-3-17
>   15:52:7\",\"user\":\"351863047772880\",\"time_stamp\":1303073527930}

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8531292/1055241   check out the accepted answer to understand the concept of interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDP is a Packet Data Protocol interface and is likely your 2.5G or 3G network interface.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPRS_Core_Network#PDP_Context

Tun interfaces are typically virtual software interfaces used to create network tunnels.

See
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. Also, as you can see 9227448 bytes is transferred from pdp interface. which means almost 9 GB! Are the statistics  wrong? or it is showing the entire data usage until now.

Comment: Hey Sarath. That would be 9MB not GB.  I'm just making an educated guess, but if the phone os is like linux/bsd those values will be reset on reboot / when the interface is re-initialized.

Comment: Hey Cepheid. I am sorry lol. I made a crazy calculation. But is this 9MB the entire data usage or is it during a particular time period?